# How to replace textarea in plugin with wp_editor

Tags: wp-editor

I would like to replace a textarea in a wordpress plugin with the wp editor if possible.
Here is the textarea code:

```
<textarea id="<?php echo esc_attr( $html['id'] ); ?>" class="awpcp-textarea required" <?php echo $html['readonly'] ? 'readonly="readonly"' : ''; ?> name="<?php echo esc_attr( $html['name'] ); ?>" rows="10" cols="50" data-max-characters="<?php echo esc_attr( $characters_allowed ); ?>" data-remaining-characters="<?php echo esc_attr( $remaining_characters ); ?>"><?php /* Content alerady escaped if necessary. Do not escape again here! */ echo $value; ?></textarea>
```

I would appreciate anyone's help. I'm not a coder per se.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Pete

Comment: I am assuming you are trying not to alter the plugin? That seems like it would be the only way.

Comment: Oh no, I could alter the plugin.  Not a problem.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to edit the plugin and insert an instance of the wp_editor instead of that textarea.

Refer to [the wp_editor function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help!!  It is much appreciated.  I will try this out and reply here as to how it goes.  Thank you again!!

Comment: I successfully replaced the textarea with wp_editor.  However it is stripping out for instance using the iframe html tag and others as well.  How can I alter this?  Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php wp_editor( $value, $html['id'], array(
    'textarea_name' => $html['name'],
    'textarea_rows' => 10,
) ); ?>
```

If you need set read only for editor see [How to make the wordpress editor readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849367/how-to-make-the-wordpress-editor-readonly)

Comment: Assuming that the question is useless and just providing an un-related different approach isnt an answer.